# Return string to an angular Service with C# controller

Tags: .net, angular

I'm trying to return a string to my angular service and it seems to desn't work.
the value of "plop" inside my service is

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator: MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: FilterOperator}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object
```

How should i do ?

Thanks

Here is my controller :

```
[HttpGet("/getuser")]
public IActionResult getUser()
{
    var email =  _userManager.GetUserName(User);
    if (email == null)
    {
        return Ok("null");
    }
    else
    {               
        return Ok(email);
    }
}
```

Here is my service :

```
getUser(): Observable<any> {
    var plop = this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/getuser', httpOptions);
    return plop;
  }
```

Comment: plop is an observable, you have to subscribe to it to get actual data

Answer (score 0):

`getUser` return an observable. You need to subscribe to it to access the data.

```
this.yourService.getUser().subscribe((item) => {

  console.log(item)
})
```

Comment: That's what i do with my function which call my service :
this.authService.getUser().subscribe(result => this.username = result);
But it return a message: "Illegal return statement" for username.